# How to copy paste from notepad to vim?

Tags: vim, copy-paste

I am new in vim and i want to copy text from gedit and paste in vim. In vim I know copy paste by command mode and visual mode but from gedit to vim I have no idea.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Copy whatever you like, in Vim, press `Shift+Insert` to paste content in clipboard into file. Make sure you are in `Insert Mode`. It works well in Ubuntu 12.10 as long as I tried.

**EDIT**
Before the paste, it is recommended to enter the `paste mode` (by `:set paste`) of vim in case you meet some un-wanted feature like incorrect auto-indent. (Thanks to @DmitryFrank)

Comment: If you paste like this (not like merlin2011 explained), it actually worths to type `:set paste` before pressing `Shift+Insert`, to make 100% sure you avoid any issues. After pasting, type `:set nopaste`.   Read `:help paste` for details.

Comment: @DmitryFrank Exactly! set the `paste mode` to prevent auto indent or other un-wanted features for pasting. I forgot to point it out. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: :set paste saved me

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running windows and using `gvim`. To copy from Notepad, just select the text and use the normal `Ctrl-C`. To paste in vim, specify the clipboard register in normal mode and use the normal `p` command like this `"+p`.

Similarly, you can go the other way with `"+yy` to grab a line from `vim`.

If you are in `Ubuntu` or some other Linux, the above trick should still work, but you need to make sure you have the full version of `vim` with `clipboard` enabled. In Ubuntu, try running `sudo apt-get install vim-gtk`.

Comment: It's worth adding that the clipboard register is a general thing, and you can use it to go the other way: `"+y` to copy.

Comment: Where did you get Notepad in Ubuntu?